# Change or disable Ubuntu global keyboard shortcut (Ctrl+Alt+Del) using terminal without using UI

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, shortcuts

I want to disable or change the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> key-shortcut in ubuntu 12.04 machine, without using the UI. Because I removed X and there is no UI to change it. I just want to do it from terminal.

Please help

Thanks,
Swaminathan

Answer (score 0):

There's a file under `~/.gconf/apps/metacity/global_keybindings` (`%gconf.xml`). You should edit this file to describe the shortcut and what the shortcut should do. I will give you an example of my shortcut config which I have configured to switch between windows using <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> in the entry below.

`<entry name="switch_windows" mtime="1363253626" type="string">
                <stringvalue>&lt;Alt&gt;Tab</stringvalue>`
All the best.